# Differences with result?

Tags: java, android, encryption

I have used a small snippet to encode, and decode a string using AES128. The issue is that it appears, that there are differences when I encode and decode on different platforms. If I run the same code on the android SDK or on the computer, I seem to get different results, even if I use the same seed/hash.

To clarify, the execution result (the encrypted value) differs from one platform to the other. In android, I get another value, and in a standard java application, I get another one.

What could possibly be wrong?

http://www.androidsnippets.com/encryptdecrypt-strings

Comment: Are you encoding them using the same charset, e.g UTF8? Or rather as it's the same codeon both platforms presumably, do you actually specify a charset?

Comment: Can you paste your small snippet?

Comment: @Mertan: Use the single OpenId to keep the single account

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow, first just a housekeeping point, it's best not to use the 'answer' option here for replying to comments, just click 'add comment'.

Have a look at this link for an example of encryption [Encrypting a String with DES](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.crypto/DesString.html)

Note the way the getBytes is qualified with "UTF8". It's then base64 encoded. Some higher levels of Android (API and onwards) have the base64 built in, otherwise it's easy enough to write your own, or just Google for Java + bas64 + example. If you use this sample code it should give you the same result on both platforms.